Webform tokens used as radio options aren't evaluated when used in handler
I'm working with a Webform where the client created two text fields that each ask for a person's name ("Who started this case?" and "Who is the other party?"). A later Radios other field ("Who is being served?") asks the submitter to either select one of the two previously entered names or select "Other..." then fill in the name of the third party.
The Radios other field is set up with [webform_submission:values:who_started] and [webform_submission:values:who_served] as the option text for its two options. When I view Webform submissions in the Drupal admin interface, or look at the Webform itself on the front end, those tokens are evaluated as expected: I see the two people's names as the options.
The form also includes a handler that sends the submission data to a third-party tool. In its JSON data, I've mapped the field on the third-party side to the token of the Radios other field: WhoIsBeingServed: "[webform_submission:values:who_is_being_served]"
This results in the third-party tool receiving the unevaluated token as its value, rather than the actual person's name. I've tried adjusting that token with :raw, :selected:option_value, etc. to no avail.
How might I adjust either my form or my handler so that a field referencing previously filled-out fields using tokens can have those tokens' values be filled in with submission data, rather than just showing their tokens?
